# Conditioning on multiple rows in a column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

> id  attribute
>
> 1   football
>
> 1   NFL
>
> 1   ball
>
> 2   football
>
> 2   autograph
>
> 2   nfl
>
> 2    blah
>
> 2    NFL

I would like to get a list of distinct ids where the attribute column contains the terms "football", "NFL", and "ball". So 1 would be included, but 2 would not. What's the most elegant/efficient way to do this in Terdata?

The number of attributes can vary for each id, and terms can repeat. For example, NFL appears twice for id 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select id
from yourtable
where attribute in ('football', 'NFL', 'ball')
group by id
having count(distinct attribute) = 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42a77/1) (*fiddle is showing MySQL, but this should work in TeraData*)

Comment: Unfortunately, terms can appear more than once for each id. I will add that above.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov this should still work, that is why I included `count(distinct attribute)`